# Is there any point in implementing LVL Licensing for a 1$ paid app on android

Tags: android

I'm about to release my first android app which I'm planning on being a paid app costing roughly 1 US Dollar.

Is there any point in licensing & obfuscating this?  For me the effort of finding and manually installing an "knock off" version wouldn't be worth the saving or the risk of the app having been changed to include malware. The idea that an android user with a $500+ handset would worry about the cost of a $1 app seems odd.

So the question is there much point in implementimenting licensing to copy protect a $1 app. I would prefer an answer that is backed with some stats.

Answer (score 0):

You can add and test the code in a couple of hours if you use the recommended `ServerManagedPolicy`. You should rather be asking if there is a reason *not* to implement it.

Comment: The reasons not to are that I'm not finding it that easy to implement. Quite a lot of people on stackoveflow have issues with it.  You also have to obfuscate which makes picking through a stack trace to fix an issue difficult and finally lots of people are reporting "false negatives" where legitimate customers cannot get into the app